# Ported C# scheduling to Scala

Tags: c#, scala, scheduled-tasks

I'm taking a design workshop and we've received a short task:

- To parse an input file of processor jobs.
- To simulate scheduling of those jobs on a parallel computer (each job needs X processors)
- The scheduling should be FCFS but it should be easy to to swap it out for a different scheduler.

I wrote the code in C# (in a few minutes) and decided this was a good opportunity to brush up on my now-two-years neglected Scala. Having done Haskell before, I feel that I'm not using Scala's capabilities. The whole code feels very stateful, and I'm sure there are things I'm complicating that could be much much simpler in idiomatic scala.

A bit about the structure: Since I'm simulating time but can't go through time since it's simulating a long time - I'm using a priority queue (on time) for my events. In order to avoid cases where I reschedule two events to the same time - I always promote unsuccessful schedules to the next `done` events. I also feel that the code could be quicker (takes 38 seconds on my laptop on the sample file).

I would really any improvement. To be fair this is a university assignment but asking on the internet on such sites was explicitly allowed.

```
import EventType.EventType
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.io.Source

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sw = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val lines = Source.fromFile( """c:\data\data.swf""").getLines()
    val maxProcessors = lines.find(_.contains("MaxProcs")).get.split(":\\s+")(1).toInt
    val data = lines.dropWhile(_.startsWith(";")).map(parseSWFJob)

    val scheduler = new FCFSScheduler(numProcessors = maxProcessors)
    data.map(scheduler.notify).flatMap(_ => scheduler.getDoneJobs).map(_.id).foreach(println) // pump
    scheduler.noMoreJobs()
    println(scheduler.getDoneJobs) // this writes to a file in the real code
    println("Time diff millis" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - sw))
  }
  def parseSWFJob(str:String) = {
    val xs = str.trim.split("\\s+").map(_.trim)
    new Job(xs(0).toLong, xs(1).toLong, xs(3).toLong, None, xs(4).toLong)
  }
}
class Job(jobId:Long ,submittedTime:Long,jobRuntime:Long, jobStartTime: Option[Long], jobRequiredProcessors: Long){
  val (id, submitTime, runtime, requiredProcessors) = (jobId, submittedTime, jobRuntime, jobRequiredProcessors)
  var startTime = jobStartTime
  override def toString = s"(id=$id,submit=$submitTime,run=$runtime,start=$startTime,procs=$requiredProcessors)"
}
object EventType extends Enumeration {
  type EventType = Value
  val Added, Retry, Done = Value
}
class FCFSScheduler(numProcessors:Long) extends JobScheduler {
  private val eventLoop = new mutable.PriorityQueue[JobEvent]()
  private var doneEvents = new mutable.TreeSet[JobEvent] {}
  private var (currentTime, runToTime, usedProcessors) = (0l, 0l, 0l) // state
  private val maxProcessors = numProcessors
  override def notify(j: Job) = {
    eventLoop.enqueue(new JobEvent(j, j.submitTime, EventType.Added))
    runToTime = j.submitTime
  }
  def releaseProcessors(j:JobEvent)= {
    doneEvents -= j
    usedProcessors -= j.job.requiredProcessors
  }
  def addJob(current: JobEvent, doneJobs: mutable.Queue[Job]):JobEvent = {
    val enoughProcessors = (maxProcessors - usedProcessors) >= current.job.requiredProcessors
    if(enoughProcessors){
      doneJobs.enqueue(current.job)
      current.job.startTime = Option(currentTime)
      usedProcessors += current.job.requiredProcessors
      var job = new JobEvent(current.job, current.job.startTime.get + current.job.runtime, EventType.Done)
      doneEvents += job
      job
    } else new JobEvent(current.job, current.time, EventType.Retry)
  }
  def retryJob(current: JobEvent, doneJobs: mutable.Queue[Job]):JobEvent = {
    val res = addJob(current, doneJobs)
    res.eType  match {
      case EventType.Done => res
      case EventType.Retry =>
        val nextSchedule: Long = if (doneEvents.nonEmpty) doneEvents.head.time else currentTime
        new JobEvent(current.job, nextSchedule , EventType.Retry)
    }
  }
  override def getDoneJobs: Iterable[Job] = {
    val currentDoneJobs = new mutable.Queue[Job]()
    while(eventLoop.nonEmpty && eventLoop.head.time >= runToTime) {
      val current = eventLoop.dequeue()
      currentTime = current.time
      current.eType match {
        case EventType.Added => eventLoop.enqueue(addJob(current, currentDoneJobs))
        case EventType.Done => releaseProcessors(current)
        case EventType.Retry => eventLoop.enqueue(retryJob(current, currentDoneJobs))
      }
    }
    currentDoneJobs
  }
  override def noMoreJobs() = runToTime = Long.MaxValue
}
class JobEvent(eventJob:Job,eventTime:Long,eventType:EventType) extends Ordered[JobEvent] {
  val (job, time, eType) = (eventJob, eventTime, eventType)
  override def compare(that: JobEvent) = {
    val tDiff = -time.compare(that.time)
    if(tDiff != 0) tDiff
    else if(eType == EventType.Done && that.eType != EventType.Done) 1
    else if(that.eType == EventType.Done && eType != EventType.Done) -1
    else -job.id.compare(that.job.id)
  }
}
trait JobScheduler {
  def notify(j: Job)
  def getDoneJobs: Iterable[Job]
  def noMoreJobs()
}
```

Comment: I already see some basic improvements (for example - the while loop) but I'm more interested in converting it to a more functional style

Answer (score 2):

Anything to do with time is inherently stateful but your code doesn't have to embrace statefulness quite, but Scala gives you some tools to address that.

Scala has simple construction of parameterized objects. You can save yourself some code (and some obscurity by using this. There is no reason, in `class JobEvent`, say, to copy `eventJob` into `job`.

One very useful state removal process you could use is to have your job dispatcher be a transformer. It takes a tuple (in a mathematical sense) of processors used, current time, jobs being processed, jobs waiting and jobs done, and transforms that it into a new tuple. What this does is allow you to use immutable data structures, and removes state from your operations.

```
abstract class ComputerSchedule(
  processorsUsed: Int, // number of processors occupied with jobs
  currentTime: Int,    // current simulated time
  inProgress: List[JobEvent], // list of jobs, ordered by ending time
  waiting: List[Job],  // list of jobs
  jobsDone: List[JobEvent]   // list of jobs, ordered by ending time
) {

  def isDone: Boolean = inProgress.empty && waiting.empty

  def nextState: ComputerSchedule
}
```

You then create a `FcfsScheduler` sub-class that implements the `nextState` method.

The transformation method finds the next (set of) `JobEvent`s that are finishing from the `inProgress` queue, calculates the available number of processors, goes to the `waiting` queue to find suitable candidate jobs, creates `JobEvent`s for each one and addes them to the newly constructed `inProgress` queue, depleting the `waiting` queue.

```
class FcfsScheduler extends ComputerSchedule {
  def nextState: ComputerSchedule = {
    // find all jobs that fit the number of processors available
    def findNextJobs(processorsAvailable: Int, candidates: List[Job]): (List[Job], List[Job]) =
      candidates match {
        case Nil => (Nil, Nil)
        case job :: tail if job.requiredProcessors <= processorsAvailable =>
          val (remainingJobs, remainingCandidates) = findNextJobs(processorsAvailable - job.requiredProcessors, tail)
          (job :: remainingJobs, remainingCandidates)
        case _ => (Nil, candidates)
     }
   // add to list by order of ending time
   def addActiveJob(j: JobEvent, jl: List[JobEvent]): List[JobEvent] = ???
   // add list of Jobs to inprocess list
   def addNextJobs(j: List[Job], jl: List[JobEvent]): List[JobEvent] = ???
   // and so on.
  }
}
```

Your simulator then consists of iterating `scheduler.nextState` until `scheduler.isDone` is true. Meanwhile, you have a complete history of your simulation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll spend some time processing this. How would performance look like? This processes millions of jobs.

Comment: If you have to deal with millions of jobs, you likely don't want to keep the state history. However, calculation times would be very similar. Data structure manipulation would be similar, as immutable data would only ever be copied, and that, rarely. The list operations would be relatively cheap, as you construct new lists, perhaps using the tail of an existing list.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know how performance looks like.